# My python list is being printed entirely in one row in a HTML table

Tags: python, list, for-loop, html-table, nested-for-loop

I am making a python script which makes a html table with a list (Without a module), but it keeps printing the entire list in one row instead of wrapping it like I need. My list is `data = ['1', '2', '3', ... , '30']`.
Im trying to get it to 5 cells in each row (not counting the side header) but I keep getting the entire list being printed in every row:

[image]

Here is a blank table for a bit of reference:

[image]

My code,

```
classes = {"ILA":'#d0e2f3', "Math":'#f5cacc', "Science":'#d9ead3', "Social<br>Studies":'#ffe598', "Academy<br>Connect!":
    '#dad2e9', "Elective":'#f9cb9c'}

file = open("/Users/EhMehMan/PythonProjects/agenda/output.html", "w")

table = "<h3>Date:__________________________________________________________</h3>\n<head>\n<style>table, th, td" \
        " {\nborder: 3px solid black;\nborder-collapse: collapse;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<table style='width:100%'>\n"

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

table += "  <tr>\n"
table += "    <th>{0}</th>\n".format(" ")
for z in days:
    table += "    <th style = 'height:74px;width:350px'>{text}</th>\n".format(text=z)
table += "  </tr>\n"


for x in classes.keys():
    table += "  <tr>\n"
    table += "    <th style='height:100px;width:100px' bgcolor='{color}'>{classes}</th>\n".format(color=classes[x],classes=x)
    for element in data:
        table += "    <td>{cell}</td>\n".format(cell = element)
    table += "  </tr>\n"
table += "</table>"
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

file.writelines(table)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: `for element in data:` iterates over the entire list. Why would you expect it not to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop `for element in data:` iterates over the entire dataset for every row. You need to adjust it to run in chunks of size `len(days)`, incrementing for each row.

There are a couple of ways of doing that. A complicated way would be to make an iterator that chunks up `data` and `zip` it with `classes.keys` in the outer loop. A much simpler approach would be to maintain a counter between runs of the outer loop:

```
for index, subject in enumerate(classes):
    table += "  <tr>\n"
    table += f"    <th style='height:100px;width:100px' bgcolor='{classes[subject]}'>{subject}</th>\n"
    for i in range(len(days)):
        table += f"    <td>{data[index * len(days) + i]}</td>\n"
    table += "  </tr>\n"
```

A faster way to do what you want would be to write to the file directly instead of accumulating a giant string in memory. Also, operate on files using a `with` block, so resources get freed up correctly in case of error. So for the example above:

```
with open("/Users/EhMehMan/PythonProjects/agenda/output.html", "w") as file:
    file.write('<h3>Date:__________________________________________________________</h3>\n')
    file.write('<head>\n')
    file.write('  <style>table, th, td {\nborder: 3px solid black;\n')
    file.write('    border-collapse: collapse;\n}\n')
    file.write('  </style>\n')
    file.write('</head>\n\n')
    file.write('<table style='width:100%'>\n')

    ...

    for index, (subject, color) in enumerate(classes.items()):
        file.write('  <tr>\n')
        file.write(f'    <th style="height:100px;width:100px" bgcolor="{color}">{subject}</th>\n')
        for i in range(len(days)):
            file.write(f'    <td>{data[index * len(days) + i]}</td>\n')
        file.write('  </tr>\n')
    file.write('</table>')
```

Notice that formatting gets a lot easier with f-strings.

Comment: This works but I still have 1 problem, I need to add the side headers and don't know how to do that with this new code.

Comment: @EhMehMan. You will have to spend a few minutes trying to figure out what the code is doing. I don't plan on writing the entire code for you.

Comment: I just need a hint to get myself on the right track.

Comment: @EhMehMan. Use `file.write`. Aside from that, nothing much needs to change. Your headers seem OK as is.

Comment: I meant the side headers with the subjects, I integrated them with the initial loop.

Comment: @EhMehMan. Gotcha. I need to update my answer very much. Hang on a sec

Comment: @EhMehMan. Take a look at the update. Hopefully I fixed the problem now.

Comment: It's all in the post. I explained how to do the chunking. You can look at the edit history if you need that level of granularity